# PayPal Manager Account Suspended. How to unlock

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I have an PayPal Manager account for using Payflow payment in my web application. Last day while i was trying to access that account from different system, not the usual IP address, then paypal was prompt me a security question, i have tried with wrong credentials, then the account has been suspended. 
Also i got mail from PayPal as the same. "Unsuccessful attempt to login to PayPal Manager from unknown IP address". 
But now i got back my security questions with answer, but can't able to reset my password.
Can any one help me out to unlock my paypal manager account ? Or to reset the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your account is locked, sometimes a password reset will not work but you can try it by going to manager.paypal.com; select: Forgot your password?

link and try from there. If that does not work contact payflow support and they'll unlock the account, reset it and give you the information.
payflow-support@paypal.com <-- they're pretty quick.

Comment: forgot your password option also saying as your account was suspended, i have mailed a request to payflow-support@papypal.com

Comment: awesome, hope it works for you Syed. Let me know if it doesn't